# No Themes being recognised in web page

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic website with two themes.

But No Themes being recognised in the web page.

Error:  Warning 1   Invalid theme or stylesheet theme value.    C:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\ThemesLab\Default.aspx   1   17  C:...\ThemesLab\

code:

```
<%@ Page Theme="Fabrikam" Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" SkinID="Logo" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textBox"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hello" CssClass="button" />

</asp:Content>
```

Any idea how to get it to work?

---

It seems to be on and off.

Will monitor it over the weeks ahead

Comment: Don't post pictures, post code. Additionally: provide us with a clear description of the problem and the steps you have taken to resolve it yourself.

Comment: I wanted to visually show you the error and the themes on the right in visual studio

Comment: Sounds like you need to apply the theme: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk.ASPX

Comment: Greg:  I am - see code above.

Comment: Note: If I move both theme folders out of app_theme it seems fine.  The app_theme folder is grey.

Comment: I just recreated the website.  Still getting the error.  Does not recognise themes !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!